# VBA retrieving Google Geocoding XML ChildNodes

Tags: xml, vba, excel, xml-parsing, geocoding

I currently got some address data records some are from the Netherlands which are correctly registered and and some are foreign which are not registered correctly.

So in order to get these addresses registered correctly I am trying to make a macro that adds the missing records to the data records by using the Google Geocoding API.

While trying to retrieve the results from the XML record I get a run-time error. 
The error is: Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)':
expected token 'eof' found '='.

//result/address_component/long_name/type-->=<--street_name

As you can see I am having difficulties with retreiving the differnt childNodes I need.

A link to the workbook with the working code, you can find the cod in the second module. (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1TucCM4DOwydnp5RDg0elJwRDQ)

An example of the xml output from the google API or see below:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

As of now I got the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub geocode()

    Dim Request         As New XMLHTTP30
    Dim Results         As New DOMDocument30
    Dim StatusNode      As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim GeoCount        As Integer
    Dim AutoResult      As Integer

    For GeoCount = 2 To 10

        On Error GoTo errorhandler

        Request.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?" _
        & "&address=" & Cells(GeoCount, 1) & " " & Cells(GeoCount, 2) & " " & Cells(GeoCount, 3) & "&sensor=false", False

        Request.send

        Results.LoadXML Request.responseText

        Set StatusNode = Results.SelectSingleNode("//status")


            If UCase(StatusNode.Text) = "OK" Then
                Cells(GeoCount, 4) = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/address_component/long_name/type=street_number").Text
                Cells(GeoCount, 5) = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/address_component/long_name/type=route").Text
                Cells(GeoCount, 6) = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/address_component/long_name/type=postal_code").Text
                Cells(GeoCount, 7) = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/address_component/long_name/type=locality").Text
                Cells(GeoCount, 8) = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/address_component/long_name/type=country").Text
                Cells(GeoCount, 9) = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/geometry/location/lat").Text
                Cells(GeoCount, 10) = Results.SelectSingleNode("//result/geometry/location/lng").Text
            Else

                For AutoResult = 4 To 10
                    Cells(GeoCount, AutoResult) = UCase(StatusNode.Text)
                Next AutoResult
            End If


    Set StatusNode = Nothing
    Set Results = Nothing
    Set Request = Nothing
errorhandler:
    Set StatusNode = Nothing
    Set Results = Nothing
    Set Request = Nothing
    Next GeoCount


End Sub
```

example off the XML return:

```
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>street_address</type>
  <formatted_address>1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>1600</long_name>
   <short_name>1600</short_name>
   <type>street_number</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</long_name>
   <short_name>Amphitheatre Pkwy</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Mountain View</long_name>
   <short_name>Mountain View</short_name>
   <type>locality</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>San Jose</long_name>
   <short_name>San Jose</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_3</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Santa Clara</long_name>
   <short_name>Santa Clara</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>California</long_name>
   <short_name>CA</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United States</long_name>
   <short_name>US</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>94043</long_name>
   <short_name>94043</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>37.4217550</lat>
    <lng>-122.0846330</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>ROOFTOP</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>37.4188514</lat>
     <lng>-122.0874526</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>37.4251466</lat>
     <lng>-122.0811574</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

Comment: `type` is not a child of `long_name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the `long_name` based off the value of its sibling `type` element

Eg:

```
Cells(GeoCount, 4) = Results.SelectSingleNode( _
     "//result/address_component[type='street_number']/long_name").Text
```

Comment: Thanks a whole lot! Managed to get the macro the work. I however still got a secondary question.

With the third and fourth address_component there are 2 types, namely locality and political. Do you by any chance know how I could interpreted these 'types'?

Comment: Sorry I'm not a big XPath user, so that next step isn't something I know...